# Need help to solve a puzzle

Tags: problems

I have been trying to solve the below chess puzzle for more than 2 days. Can someone help me to solve it?

**White to play and mate in two moves**

```
[FEN "n1N1Kn/2p/P1k/2p1Q/P/2P/7B/6Nq w - - 0 1"]
```

I have tried to do it, but my tries take more than two moves.

```
[FEN "n1N1Kn/2p/P1k/2p1Q/P/2P/7B/6Nq w - - 0 1"]

1. c4 Qf3 2.  Nxf3 Nb6 3. Ne7#
```

Comment: BTW, white pawns are going top and black ones should go bottom. I am not much good in chess. so thought to make this a point. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe 1. Qe2 and zugzwang:

1... Nb6 2. Ne7#

1... Kd5 2. Ne7#

1... Qd5 2. Qb5#

1... c4  2. Qc4#

1...Qxh2 2. Qe4#

Comment: The puzzle should be completed in two moves of white.. this puzzle is in my mobile app.

Comment: Please check my updated post..

Comment: @Mr_Green it does seem that 1.Qe2 is correct...

Comment: @RauanSagit yes I got that now.. but how this worked? what is the danger to black king if I keep the white queen on Qe2? please explain..

Comment: @Mr_Green Well, after 1.Qe2 black has to make a move. And any move that black makes will lose. The white queen on e2 allows Qe2-b5, Qe2-c4 as well as Qe2-e6 and control over g2, f3 and e4. The white queen has to control all these squares in order to deliver a checkmate in move two.

Comment: @Mr_Green, as @RauanSagit said, any move that black makes will lose. This kind of situations are called `zugzwang`

Comment: Also 1...Ng6 2. Qe6#